# h.264 stream not displayed on IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, h.264

I have a app where I used to show video streaming and the app player it. Until IOS 5 everything was working like a charm.

With the new update to IOS 6, the player to reproduce the video doesn't work when the video streaming is this format: h.264. In other format of video, still working.

Any idea,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain how you are trying to do video streaming, live streaming (HLS), rtsp  or some other.

live streaming should not have any issues under ios 6 and as far as I know non of the 3rd party rtsp libs I am aware of have any issues with ios 6. And of course non streaming h264 (progressive download) works as well as it ever did